# Getting a dynamically positioned substring from a cat output

Tags: linux, rhel

I have command in a script that looks something like this:

```
echo "- user:$(cat /var/users.txt)" >>  /opt/tag/user_new.txt
```

Issues is `users.txt` contains set of user in format like this *john-davis@gmail.com* etc.

However what I want is just the part before `@` i.e. *john-davis*, so that string that I append in `user_new.txt` is this `- user:john-davis`.

Basically a bash version of firstIndexOf and substring along with echo. Can someone help me with how this can be acheived in a single command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those braces look wrong -- I assume you intend process expansion.

I would skip the echo, and process expansion too. Something like:

```
awk '-F@' '{ print "- user:" $1 }' /var/users.txt >> /opt/tag/user_new.txt
```